# Recursive mutex with FSU Pthread implementation

Tags: recursion, pthreads, mutex, recursive-mutex

I am wondering whether the Florida State University implementation of the pthread standard is, by any chance, able to handle the recursive mutexes.
Unfortunately the documentation about the FSU implementation is rather poor, and it does not mention of the possibility or not to declare a mutex as recursive.

Trying to declare a mutex as follows:

```
pthread_mutex_attr mutex_attr;
pthread_mutexattr_init (&mutex_attr);
pthread_mutexattr_settype(&mutex_attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
```

and compiling using the FSU pthreads library, I got this list of errors:

```
test.c:25: error: `pthread_mutex_attr' undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:25: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
test.c:25: error: for each function it appears in.)
test.c:25: error: parse error before "mutex_attr"
test.c:27: error: `mutex_attr' undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:28: error: `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Trying to compile the same code with the (non-FSU) pthread implementation on my machine, it works.

To avoid trivialities, I tell you in advance that, by default, the POSIX mutexes are not recursive.

Should I conclude that there is no way to make use of recursive mutexes with the FSU implementation, or there is another way to achieve these (i.e. another way to declare a mutex as recursive)?

Comment: The type is `pthread_mutex_attr_t` note the _t.

Comment: Ben, you are right, in effect the code I wrote was only an attempt to get the output of the compiler.. The original code was correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the FSU pthreads implementation does not support recursive mutexes. In fact, the [latest release](http://moss.csc.ncsu.edu/~mueller/pthreads/) has no notion of mutex types. In addition to lacking the `PTHREAD_MUTEX_*` mutex type names, it also omits the `pthread_mutexattr_settype()` and `pthread_mutexattr_gettype()` functions used to manipulate the mutex type.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, so, considering that, I think I should modify the flow of my application to avoid the lock nesting.